# Обращение к свойству объекта в php

Tags: php

Как обратиться к свойству объекта которое имеет в начале знак `$`?
Пробовал:

```
$object->$property;
$object->'$property';
```

Или только `foreach` использовать?

В объекте возвращается всегда 1 свойство.

В некоторых объектах свойства называются просто `$`.

Comment: `$object->property`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы про это?

```
$data = "{'$':1, '\$field':2}";

$obj = json_decode($data);

print_r($obj);

echo $obj->{"$"};
echo $obj->{"\$field"};   // $obj->{'$field'}
```

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы обратиться к синтаксически некорректному имени свойства можно воспользоваться специальным синтаксисом:

```
$obj = (object) ['$property' => 1];
echo $obj->{'$property'};
```

Строка имени свойства может быть любой, лишь бы была записана как корректный строковой литерал